# Value not getting replaced during logging to Application Insight from Identity Server

Tags: identity-server, logging, application-insights

**Sitecore.NET 10.1.1 (rev. 005862) in Azure PAAS Scaled**

What I am trying to do:

I want to write the logs into the Application Insights for the Sitecore Identity server.

What is the current status:
Entries are being made to the Application Insight. Unfortunately, the values are not getting replaced. Though they are getting written properly in the log file and under 'Rendered message' in Application Insight.

There is no such issue with logs from other Sitecore instances.

For example:

1. Entry in Application Insight:

   a) As heading:

   ***Executed action {ActionName} in {ElapsedMilliseconds}ms***

   b) As rendered message:

***Executed action "Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer.Controllers.AccountController.Login (Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer)" in 14.6278ms***

[image]

2. Entry in the log file as seen through Kudu.

   ***Executed action "Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer.Controllers.AccountController.Login (Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer)" in 14.6278ms***

So, what is going wrong and how to debug it or fix it?

Comment: Can you share what you have done so far to get the current message in application insights?

Comment: Sitecore has shared https://github.com/serilog-contrib/serilog-sinks-applicationinsights/issues/11 as they expect it  to be a Serilog issue.